# parse a json file with several elements

Tags: arrays, json

I'm blocked at trying to parse this specific json content.

I can parse the content, but I can not find out how to loop through each element of the result because of the header of each element of the object change accross the result

this is the code I wrote in google app script

```
function myFunction() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1xqnMYtkZ2iST3xqzs_zKqHwzC017VHqd");
  var text = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var json = JSON.parse(text);
  Logger.log(json)
}
```

the json content is as below

```
{
"dlg-0093d9ca-b42d-4b3c-9a89-c872000915f6": [
    {
        "utteranceID": 0,
        "speaker": "agent",
        "source": "[F]text[/F]",
        "target": ""
    },
    {
        "utteranceID": 1,
        "speaker": "customer",
        "source": "Hi. I'm trying to buy movie tickets at the AMC Houston 8 in Houston, Texas.",
        "target": ""
    }

],
"dlg-00d44b07-4d5e-42ae-ba74-b445f1e23004": [
    {
        "utteranceID": 0,
        "speaker": "agent",
        "source": "Hi how are you?",
        "target": ""
    },
    {
        "utteranceID": 1,
        "speaker": "customer",
        "source": "Good. How are you?",
        "target": ""
    },
    {
        "utteranceID": 2,
        "speaker": "agent",
        "source": "Great, thanks for asking, how can I help you?",
        "target": ""
    }
],
"dlg-097887e5-303c-4757-80e6-dd4630621f09": [
    {
        "utteranceID": 0,
        "speaker": "agent",
        "source": "How can I help you?",
        "target": ""
    },
    {
        "utteranceID": 1,
        "speaker": "customer",
        "source": "Hi. I'm looking to book some movie tickets.",
        "target": ""
    },
    {
        "utteranceID": 2,
        "speaker": "agent",
        "source": "Okay what film did you want?",
        "target": ""
    },
    {
        "utteranceID": 3,
        "speaker": "customer",
        "source": "Glass.",
        "target": ""
    }
]
```

}

============

UPDATE:
What I want to achieve is to copy the value of "source" element to the "target", and return the a new json content with the updated content.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: You could just loop on the keys:
`for (key in json) { console.log(json[key]) } `

Comment: thanks @AlexandreLéonard. This is what I wanted to have

Comment: sorry to add more question guys:
what if I want to copy the content of each "source" element to "target", and after this rebuild the json content?

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop over the json object will allow you to iterate over each named element of the json. A traditional for loop to iterate over the array of object for each key in the json will allow you to perform the edit step. See code below:

```
for (key in json) {
  the_array = json[key]
  for (var i = 0, l = the_array.length; i < l; i++) {
    item = the_array[i]
    item.target = item.source
  }
}
console.log(json)
```